# How do I control a CSS property using a HTML range or number input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The project is a .gif image moving from left to right with the parameter of left: 0% : left: 100% in CSS.
An end result is an input form in which an input text is 1 - 100 and will move a guy from left to right with a slider.

I am having trouble understanding this interaction between the EventListener and the HTTP element and it´s driving me mad!

I´ve read a lot on controlling values via JS setAttribute and the CSS Custom Property and so far can only get the mouse control to work.
I´ve got my current snippet of a template below for one of the characters, this is missing something and I can´t work it out.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("charinput"); 

let root = document.documentElement;
root.addEventListener("value", myInput => {
  root.style.setProperty("--chari1-positionx", myInput);
});

window.onload = function addPlayers() {
  var charDiv = document.createElement("div")
  charDiv.setAttribute("class", "infob");
  charDiv.setAttribute("margin-top", "325px");
  document.body.appendChild(charDiv)
  var char = document.createElement("img");
  char.setAttribute("src", "assets/Char.gif");
  char.setAttribute("height", "150");
  char.setAttribute("class", "chari1");
charDiv.appendChild(char)
}
```

```css
:root {
  --chari1-positionx: 0%;
}
.chari1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  padding: 0%;
  animation: runner 7s;
  left: var(--chari1-positionx);
}
```

```html
<div class="charUpdate">
<input type="range" id="charinput" min="1" max="100">
<input type="submit" id="charinput" value="Update Position">
</div>
```

After this stage I´ll be using the setItem and getItem functions to save these values and change them. 
For now, I want to better understand the interaction between any given HTML input and a JS EventListener.

The end result will ideally be a user inputting a number between 1 to 100, it changes the position of the image and stays there.
At the moment, my character starts at the 0% position. Changing the --chari1-positionx value does reflect in the end result but the HTML Input has no effect on the live position.

Any tips and/or resources will be really appreciated! I haven´t touched JQuery yet and I´m not sure if it´s needed, but I will dive in if so!

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what your issue is? (Your question as-is is a bit vague)

Comment: Sorry, long night.

How do I control a CSS property using a HTML input?

So I want the CSS left: _value_ to change via a HTML text input and I´m definitely missing something.

Using an input field, like the _range_ one in my code currently, how to move the .gif left and right respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you have 2 inputs with the same 'charinput' id. I've modified these to 'charinput-range' and 'charinput-submit', in the code below.

Direct update when dragging the range:

```
document.getElementById('charinput-range').addEventListener('input', function(e){
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--chari1-positionx', e.target.value + '%');
});
```

Update when clicking the submit button:

```
document.getElementById('charinput-submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var currentValue = document.getElementById('charinput-range').value;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--chari1-positionx', currentValue + '%');
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, got it to work

All that was needed was this and to wrap the EventListener with `window.addEventListener("click", function(){` and now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're misunderstanding how `addEventListener` works. You can't add a "watcher" to an input element's value as such. What you can do is to instead listen to the `input` event on the element, and then update your values accordingly. This also means you can ditch the "Update Position" button entirely: however, if you wish to keep it, you can also invoke the same logic to set the CSS variable in the root by listening to the click event on the button.

The code below assumes that you change your "submit" input to a button of ID `update`:

```
const myInput = document.getElementById("charinput");
const update = document.getElementById("update");

function updatePosition() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--chari1-positionx", `${+myInput.value}%`);
}

// Update position when input event is fired from your range input
myInput.addEventListener("input", updatePosition);

// Update position if user clicks on button (this is not necessary, really)
update.addEventListener("click", updatePosition);
```

See the full proof-of-concept example here:

```js
const myInput = document.getElementById("charinput");
const update = document.getElementById("update");

function updatePosition() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--chari1-positionx", `${+myInput.value}%`);
}

// Update position when input event is fired from your range input
myInput.addEventListener("input", updatePosition);

// Update position if user clicks on button (this is not necessary, really)
update.addEventListener("click", updatePosition);

window.onload = function addPlayers() {
  var charDiv = document.createElement("div")
  charDiv.setAttribute("class", "infob");
  charDiv.setAttribute("margin-top", "325px");
  document.body.appendChild(charDiv)
  var char = document.createElement("img");
  char.setAttribute("src", "assets/Char.gif");
  char.setAttribute("height", "150");
  char.setAttribute("class", "chari1");
  charDiv.appendChild(char)
}
```

```css
:root {
  --chari1-positionx: 0%;
}

.chari1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  padding: 0%;
  animation: runner 7s;
  left: var(--chari1-positionx);
}
```

```html
<div class="charUpdate">
  <input type="range" id="charinput" min="1" max="100">
  <button type="button" id="update">Update Position</button>
</div>
```